# jQuery not selecting <td> with specific attribute

Tags: jquery

jQuery not selecting `<td>` with specific attribute. Every other element works fine except `<td> <th> <tr> <thead>`

```
    $('[HelpName]').mouseenter(function () {
        if (help == 1) {
            var itemName = $(this).attr('HelpName');
            $('#status').html(arrLang[user_lang][itemName]);
        }

    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        if (help == 1) {
            $('#status').html('');
        }
    });
```

Comment: You probably have a mouseenter listener higher up (or lower down with capture) that calls `preventDefault()` on the event. Try this code on an empty page without further event handlers and see if you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum there are no mouseenter events above or below. Table is loaded via PHP, but whole jQuery is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function () { });`

Comment: What happened when you tried to reproduce it in an empty page?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum then it works. Thank you, I will keep looking.

Comment: You can see event handlers in the developer tools and put breakpoints when certain events happen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `$(document).on('mouseenter', '[HelpName]', function () {` because elements are loaded in DOM afterwards.